# Field is not updated

Tags: 2010, list, powershell, updatelistitems

I try to update a list item, with PowerShell:

```
try{
$root = GetRootSite #this function returns the site collection url
$site = New-Object -Type Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite -ArgumentList $root
$customerlist = "Customer-List"
$customers = $site.RootWeb.Lists[$customerlist]

$spqQuery = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery 
$spqQuery.Query =  "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name = 'ID' Ascending = 'TRUE'/></OrderBy><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='CODE' /><Value Type='Text'>TEST</Value></Eq></Where>" 

$spSourceItems = $customers.GetItems($spqQuery)  

foreach ($i in $spSourceItems) {
$code = $i["CODE"]
write-host $code

[string]$currentlink = $i["LinkToOperations"] -as [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldUrlValue]
$linktooperations = $root + "/Customers/" + $code
if ($currentlink -eq "") {


    $field = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldURLValue
    $field.Description = $code
    $field.Url = $linktooperations

$i["LinkToOperations"] = $field
$i["CustomerURLText"] = "Updated"
$i.Update

write-host $i["LinkToOperations"]
write-host $i["CustomerURLText"]

}
}
$spSourceItems.Update
$customers.Update
}
catch {
    Write-Host "error" 
    $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
    Write-Host $ErrorMessage
    exit    #exit if cannot load the files above

}
```

Basically, if the link is empty, I want to add it. My problem is that when the code runs, the correct output is written to the console, but I don't see the results in the list. The $i object is the listitem returned by a query. I have full control on the list, no error is thrown during the process.
The `LinkToOperations` is a url field, the `CustomerURLText` is text.
I also get the following output upon finish:

> MemberType          : Method OverloadDefinitions : {System.Void
>   Update(), System.Void Update(bool bFromMigration)} TypeNameOfValue
>   : System.Management.Automation.PSMethod Value               :
>   System.Void Update(), System.Void Update(bool bFromMigration) Name
>   : Update IsInstance          : True

what am i missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading through your code, Update call has been used like a property without brackets. It should be a method call as :

```
    $i["LinkToOperations"] = $field
    $i["CustomerURLText"] = "Updated"
    $i.Update()
```

Comment: Ah, yes, the brackets. Thank you, this was the solution.

Comment: Awesome ! Good to know that it worked .

Answer (score 1):

A URL field in SharePoint is the URL and the description. You haven't included all of your code, so I can't tell if you're accessing it wrong, but the below example (from [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/5eac4e2c-dac8-4016-a168-0c1f6064bb11/powershell-update-sharepoint-url-description-from-title-field?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious)) should help.

```
Write-Host "Adding New Link"
$field = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldURLValue
$field.Description = "Microsoft"
$field.URL = "http://www.microsoft.com"
$item = $list.Items.Add()
$item["URL"] = $field
$item["Comments"] = "Added From PowerShell"
$item.Update()
```

Comment: I added the full code to the question. Also added the Description, but this didn't solve the issue. Also, the other, simple text field remains blank too.